# How to set flyway path configuration for test using filesystem in configuration file?

Tags: spring-boot, flyway, spring-boot-test

I have setup flyway task for Local using a configuration file and wiring up to my task like

```
tasks.create<FlywayMigrateTask>("migrateLocal") {
    configFiles = arrayOf("config/flyway/flyway.conf")
}
```

This task runs okay and the scripts are executed well, However when I try running integration tests with an application-TEST.yaml file where I define the configuration paths, I get the error below

```
Flyway failed to initialize: none of the following migration scripts locations could be found:

    - classpath:db/migration
```

The thing is I dont want to redefine the same configurations in the test folder, I want to reference them from file system using my application-TEST.yaml in the resources folder of test package like this

```
flyway:
    schemas: public
    locations: filesystem:doc/flyway/migrations,filesystem:config/flyway/archive,filesystem:config/flyway/post_migrations
```

If I try that, I get the same Flyway failed to initialize when I ran a single test, infact context fails to load

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to set up something similar, You have to annotate the integration test with

```
@ActiveProfiles("TEST")
```

"TEST" is the configuration profile ("application-TEST.yaml").

Everything worked okay after that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I fixed that error by creating in the `src/main/resources` project´s folder another that would be named `db` which in turn contains another folder called `migration` and there I placed the script for creating the table `my_table`. The schema I declared in tag `spring.flyway.schemas` of the application.properties file and flyway will add `my_table` and another table `flyway_schema_history`.